# 20 errors in relation to "[Vue Warn] property or method not defined on instance but referenced during render"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a number of errors in my code, coming up as

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "tableItems" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

(in this example I am using tableItems, but there are others...). 
I am struggling to find an answer as none seem to be similar to this...
Following is my code:


Html:

```
<v-data-table :headers="tableHeaders" :items="tableItems" hide-actions>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.date }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.firstThing }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.secondThing }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.thirdThing }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.firdThing }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fourthThing }}</td>
          <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
            <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="teal">Edit</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="pink">Delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
data: {
tableItems: [ ' ' ],
},

methods: {
initialize () {
      this.tableItems = [
        {
          date: new Date(),
          firstThing: 'Me',
          secondThing: 'Someone',
          thirdThing: 'a type',
          fourthThing: 6,
          fifthTHing: 'working on this...'
        },
      ]
    },
editItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.tableItems.indexOf(item)
}
});
```

I hope this all makes sense, and I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Shantel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to write this:

```
data() {
    return {
      tableItems: ''
    }
},
```

instead of:

```
    data: {
tableItems: [ ' ' ],
},
```

actually yes, it does not have to be a function. There is just a comma that i suppouse have to be removed:

```
    data: {
tableItems: [ ' ' ]
},
```

Comment: If I may clarify, are they not both different ways of defining a function?

Comment: @ShantelPike No. `data()` is a function that returns an object. What you were writing is an object itself that Vue can't detect.

Comment: @KaungMyatLwin and Evgeniia: the root component / app does not have to provide `data` as a function, as implicitly stated in the [Vue guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function). A function is necessary if you _re-use_ the component.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a previous error that was influencing this one, which I was able to fix. Thanks again.